# Static library dependency + VS2010 + SVN

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

this is a doubt about solution organization in Visual Studio using SVN.

To simplify, let's suppose I have a static library called Util.lib, compiled in  a VS2010 project.

I have also a static library called Capture.lib , compiled in VS2010, that depends on Util.lib.
On the SVN, Util.lib is an external in the Capture.lib folder, and the Util project was added to the Capture.lib solution.
This compiles perfectly.

Now the problem. I have another project, called Native, that compiles a DLL.
This DLL depends on Capture.lib AND Util.lib.
I have added both as externals, and added the projects to the Native solution.

The problem is: during the compilation of Native, the Capture.lib project can´t compile because it doesn´t find Util.lib.
This happens because it looks for in on the externals folder of the Capture project! And the Util is not there now.

What should I do in this case? Should I add the Util project (inside the externals/Capture/externals/Util) to the Native
solution? Is this the correct approach?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how often Util.lib and Capture.lib are changed.
1) In case you are using their fixed versions for Native.dll, you just need to add
Util.lib and Capture.lib and their headers folders to your Native project
(Project->Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories, Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies)
2) In case Capture.lib and Native.dll are changing dinamically in parallel with Native.dll,
you should both ajust dependencies in the same manner as (1) and add project dependencies to Capture.lib and Native.dll (Project->Project Dependencies) where you can tell VS to compile your projects in the right order.